# angularjs : ng-include not working in another view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to include a template and its not working.I have had trouble with includes every single time I try to use them. Is there something I am doing wrong?

views structure :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFeYs.png

UserList.html :

```
<p>
    UserList
</p>
<div ng-include src="'../Partials/Paging.html'"></div>
```

**update :**

```
Paging   : localhost/Administrator/App/Views/User/UserList.html 
UserList : localhost/Administrator/App/Views/Partials/Paging.html 
Index    : localhost/Administrator/Index.html
```

Comment: where is your index.html ? try with  `src="Partials/Paging.html"`

Comment: paging : http://localhost/Administrator/App/Views/Partials/Paging.html ---- and index : http://localhost/Administrator/Index.html

Comment: Please try whether the path given in my answer is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Your include path starts on your index.html, since its loaded from there while running your SPA.
So your include path has to be relative to your index.html:

```
<div ng-include="'App/Views/Partials/Paging.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div ng-include="'App/Views/Partials/Paging.html'"></div>
```

`ng-include` doesn't requires src parameter. If you still see any error please verify the path to `Paging.html`

Comment: not worked... this code  : `    <div ng-include="'App/Views/Partials/Paging.html'"></div>
` worked in Index.html why ?

Comment: see my answer above. Include pathes are resolved relative from your index.html

Comment: You are currently inside the Administrator folder. You need to move into App/Views/Partials/Paging.html from the current location. So this url path is the required one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-include="'../Partials/Paging.html'"></div>
```

till if you will not get the src path might be wrong